# allMarkdownRemark does not return any results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to do part 6 of the tutorial on Transformer plugins ([link](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-six/)). I created a .md file in the src directory. I used GraphiQL and ran the following:

```
{
  allMarkdownRemark {
    edges {
      node {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and this is what it returns:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allMarkdownRemark": {
      "edges": []
    }
  }
}
```

Even though I have a .md file in the src directory. Here is my gatsby-config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Pandas Eating Lots',
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `src`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
    `gatsby-plugin-emotion`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-typography`,
      options: {
        pathToConfigModule: `src/utils/typography`,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-starter-hello-world",
  "private": true,
  "description": "A simplified bare-bones starter for Gatsby",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,json,md}\"",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/core": "^10.0.27",
    "gatsby": "^2.18.12",
    "gatsby-plugin-emotion": "^4.1.18",
    "gatsby-plugin-typography": "^2.3.20",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.1.43",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.6.45",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-typography": "^0.16.19",
    "typography": "^0.16.19",
    "typography-theme-kirkham": "^0.16.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "^1.19.1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
  }
}
```

and this is my file structure:

[image: file structure]

I would appreciate if anyone could help me figure out what is going on.

Comment: Every `MarkdownRemark` node should have a `File` parent node. Do you see your md file among the results of a `allFile` query? I would suggest moving your markdown to dedicated directory and point `gatsby-source-filesystem` to it.

Comment: @Z.Zlatev yes, allFile shows the md file, but it still doesn't show in the allMarkdownRemark

Comment: then `gatsby-transformer-remark` might be failing to create a `MarkdownRemark` node out of it for some reason. But seriously, don't source your entire `src` directory. It's for your app source code, not the content.

Comment: I changed it to src/posts and tried reinstalling gatsby-transformer-remark, still no luck :/

Comment: Your markdown might not be valid. Try downloading some valid one to test it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your "file structure" looks like vscode. The icon for the markdown file is wrong, so i think you copied the name of the file from the tutorial and entered it via copy/paste. BUT: the filename has a blank at the end, and so this is not recognized as a markdown file but as a file with an `".md "` extension (not the blank). rename it and you will see a correct markdown-icon in vscode and the file will be detected

Comment: This was from a while back, but yes you're right. If anyone has this issue make sure your md file has the right extension.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the order of plugins at *gatsby-config.js*, putting **gatsby-transformer-remark** first. It's worked for me.